# How to count how many items for distinct items in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Imagine a have a table with a column named status:

```
status
------
A
A
A
B
C
C
D
D
D
```

How can I count how many rows have A, how many rows have B etc?
this kind of output:

```
A  |B  |C  |D  |E  
------------------
3  |1  |2  |3  |0
```

As for E = O , this will always be A,B,C,D and E 
Output should be one row (thus 1 query).

When doing a distinct count (most returning answer on my searches, it does return how many different elements there are, 4 in this case...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting the results into one row is a bit more clumsy that group by:

```
Select
    sum(status = 'A') 'A',
    sum(status = 'B') 'B',
    sum(status = 'C') 'C',
    sum(status = 'D') 'D',
    sum(status = 'E') 'E'
From 
    my_table
```

Some databases support `pivot` which makes this a bit better. MySQL isn't one of them.

**<kbd>[Example SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1c37e/2)</kbd>**

Comment: Thanks for the simplier solution eggyal, I'll set this as the correct answer as it is the one-line solution as in the question but upvotes yours as it is clean.

Comment: @VincentDuprez: Fair enough, but do be aware that this approach will not scale very nicely (it will always require a full table scan).

Comment: Not every database will let you treat conditions as a 1 or 0 in this way.

Comment: @Laurence: Agreed, but question is tagged [tag:mysql].

Answer (score 3):

You simply need to *group* your table, applying a suitable aggregate function:

```
SELECT   status, COUNT(*)
FROM     my_table
GROUP BY status
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1c37e/1/0).

If a status is missing, you can treat it as 0 from within your application code.

Comment: I was hoping to see a one row output solution but I can use it this way too, thanks, will accept your answer in 8 minutes

Comment: @VincentDuprez: It's *possible* to get the results in a single row, but this is definitely the recommended approach as it will be far more efficient - especially if the `status` column is indexed.